# 2 Wörter mit selber Vorsilbe bei einem Querstrich

Tags: grammaticality

Nehmen wir mal die Wörter "unabsichtlich" und "unwissentlich". Wie würde man diese korrekt mit einem Querstrich notieren, im Sinne von unabsichtlich/wissentlich. Wird dort ein Bindestrich benötigt, oder muss man korrekterweise beide ausschreiben?

Answer (score 9):

Das Satzzeichen heißt hier - obwohl es gleich aussieht - nicht Bindestrich, sondern *Ergänzungsstrich*.

Nach den Rechtschreibregeln §98 darf man in Aufzählungen einen gleichen Wortbestandteil auslassen und die Auslassung mit einem Ergänzungsstrich markieren.

Ein analoges Beispiel für die Auslassung einer Vorsilbe wird dort mit

> heranführen oder -schleppen

genannt. Ob das jetzt guter Stil ist, sich gar "lohnt" (für die Einsparung eines einzelnen Buchstabens), kann man sicher diskutieren - Ich persönlich finde, dass mein Auge bei etwas wie

> unabsichtlich oder -wissentlich

(was die demnach richtige Verkürzungsschreibweise wäre) stolpert und

> unabsichtlich oder unwissentlich

wesentlich leichter und eingängiger zu lesen ist, vor allem, weil im diesen Fall  das mit der Auslassung versehene *-wissentlich* auch ein gültiges Wort ist und genau das Gegenteil des Beabsichtigten bedeutet, und das erste Wort mehrere Möglichkeiten bietet, welche Silbe(n) denn nun ausgelassen wurden. Das führt dazu, dass man erstmal nachdenken muss, was denn das Wort nun bedeuten soll (Was aber bei dem ähnlich unglücklich gewählten Beispiel aus den Rechtschreibregeln fast noch schlimmer ist: Lautet das zweite Verb jetzt "heranschleppen" oder "herschleppen"?).

Comment: Diese Regeln sind auch umgekehrt anwendbar, wenn man das gleiche Wortende einmal weglässt, und die mit einem Ergänzungsstrich ersetzt, oder? Also im Sinne von Vor- oder Nachsicht.

Comment: Ja, genau. Und sogar beides: *Textilgroß- und Einzelhandel*, hier wurde bei ersten Wort (*Textilgroßhandel*) das Wortende, beim zweiten (*Textileinzelhandel*) der Anfang weggelassen. Da "lohnt" es sich wirklich ;)

Comment: Danke, dass doppelte wäre aber etwas missverständlich in meinen Augen.

Comment: Mein Beispiel finde ich verständlicher als deins - Vor allem ist es gängiger.